# Change default Active directory on enterprise agreement azure subscription

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am attempting to change the active directory of a newly created EA subscription, from my companies AD to a new AD that I created in the sub. According to https://www.itunity.com/article/how-to-change-the-default-directory-for-an-existing-azure-subscription-2494 and other sites, it is simple as clicking the edit directory button. But when I goes to the list of subscriptions in the old azure portal, that button does not appear.

My guess is that the portal isn’t allowing this due to the fact that it is an EA subscription. Because when I logged into my own personal subscription, which is not EA, the button appears as expected. Is this in fact the reason?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, it is because you have signed in with a Work account.

"The Edit Directory command in the Azure classic portal is not available to users who are signed in using a work or school account because those accounts can sign in only to the directory to which they belong."

See this link for more: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-understanding-resource-access/

Comment: "those accounts can sign in only to the directory to which they belong" ??? There is a rather huge hole here in understanding why or what other account should be used besides the one to which I belong.