# How do I Choose which AAD you Create the Service Principal in?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, service-principal

I can't find any documentation on how to choose which AAD to create the service principal in. Basically, I can't find out if there is even a way to add the SP to the local AAD.

So we have a default Global AD which covers all of our enrollment and below that all subscriptions. I'm using Powershell derived from the many many examples on the net to create a SP in the default AD. Then I permission that SP against the subscription it is going to be working in.

At this point I've run into the following problem.
I'm rolling out a Key Vault, this works.

```
New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $VaultName -EnabledForDeployment -EnabledForTemplateDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -Verbose
```

I need to add the first secret into it as part of the deployment. This bit fails because the SP doesn't have access to the KV.

```
# Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $VaultName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -PermissionsToSecrets get,set -ServicePrincipalName $ServicePrincipalName
```

This is the result of that command.

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy : Cannot find the Active Directory object 
'Service-Principal-Name' in tenant '6166a717-xxxx-xxxxx-b0e8-6b7288c1f7ec'. 
Please make sure that the user or application service principal you are
authorizing is registered in the current subscription's Azure Active 
directory.
```

Reading into this, its not possible to set the Global AD Service Principal to have get/set on the local Keyvault. it would have to be a local Service Principal. However, we dont have one of them and nowhere can I work out how to create one of them.

Anyone else feeling this pain and know how to resolve it?

Comment: It looks like your $ServicePrincipalName contains a value 'Service-Principal-Name' instead of the Application Id? Make sure this application exist in your Azure AD tenant.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings section of the old portal (manage.windowsazure.com), you will find a list of all subscriptions. The fourth column (Directory) shows the default directory that is associated with each subscription. No matter what, you will have to create the Service Principal in the Directory that is associated with that particular subscription. Please check [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory/) link to understand the relationship between Subscriptions and AAD.

Comment: are you saying there is a way to change the default directory for a subscription? if so, how does that affect authentication against a subscription in future for all other entities that try and access it?

Comment: Yes. You can change the default directory in the same settings page in the old portal but I believe it can only be accessed by the Service Administrator / creator of the subscription. As for the second part of the question, from what I understand, it depends on how you want to implement. You can have a single SP that handles authentication for all entities or you can create SP for each type of entity that wants to access the resource.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in powershell though, having to drop into the portal each time we run a deployment won't help.

Comment: It turns out that i have no ability to change the default directory for the subscription that I'm working against. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345145/change-default-active-directory-on-enterprise-agreement-azure-subscription